# C# run batch file with argument with spaces

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I need to run batch file, which has path (can contains spaces) as argument.

Batch file is really simple:

> echo off
>
> echo %1 > echotest.txt

Csharp code I am using to run this batch file:

```
   ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                        info.UserName = KIM_USER;
                        info.Password = ConvertToSecureString(KIM_USER_PASSWORD);
                        info.FileName = theTask.Path;
                        info.Arguments = "\"" + TranslateParameter(theTask.Parameter) + "\"";
                        info.Domain = Environment.MachineName;
                        info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(theTask.Path);
                        info.UseShellExecute = false;
                        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        Process batProcess = Process.Start(info);
                        batProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Basically in parameter comes e.g {Test_Path} and this is in TranslateParameter converted to real path, e.g: D:\Test Path\ (contains spaces)

This does not work for me, it returns me exit code 1 everytime.

If i remove \" from info.Arguments, it works, but in output file is just D:\Test

Any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: I just tried this and it works for me. Not sure why it's not working for you...

Comment: It looks clean to me

Comment: Did you guys set UseShellExecute to False, and set UserName and Password? If i remove this lines, it also works for me.

Comment: I didn't set username and password.

Comment: Thats the problem. If you dont set, it works. When you set it, doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this if that works:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.UserName = KIM_USER;
info.Password = ConvertToSecureString(KIM_USER_PASSWORD);
info.FileName = theTask.Path + " \"" + TranslateParameter(theTask.Parameter) + "\"";
//info.Arguments = "\"" + TranslateParameter(theTask.Parameter) + "\"";
info.Domain = Environment.MachineName;
info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(theTask.Path);
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process batProcess = Process.Start(info);
batProcess.WaitForExit();
```